# Rails 3.1: Where to place SCSS mixins/variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

Just playing around with Rails 3.1 at the moment, and one issue I'm having is wondering where to place SCSS variables and mixins.

What I mean is, what with scss stylesheets being separated by controller, I'm wondering where to put SCSS variables so that I won't need to redeclare them in every separate stylesheet. I'm guessing there's a standard place?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a "_base" partial. Put all your stuff in there then include it in application.css.scss and include everything in there that way it inherits from "_base"

Make sure you use SASS `@import "*/*";` for the includes and not sprockets, as sprockets doesn't carry over the variables since it's not the SASS engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at twitter's bootstrap and see how it's organized

Comment: Twitter bootstrap has LESS not SCSS. But yeah it can serve as an example one way or another.

Comment: a simple google search would reveal that there are active people who maintain sass and scss versions of twitter's bootstrap. and anyway, there's practically no big difference between less and the others, so for this purpose, getting it straight from the source would be okay